# Problem install phpmyadmin on amazon ec2?

Tags: amazon-ec2, installation

I googled on how to install phpmyadmin on ec2, and i got this syntax:

```
sudo yum install phpmyadmin
```

But i keep getting this:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
amzn-main                                                | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates                                             | 2.1 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
No package phpmyadmin available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I tried to go my website, its not installed. Please help

EDIT:

My Server OS: Amazon Linux AMI 64 bit

I tried: yum install phpmyadmin --enablerepo=development, but still I got this error:

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, priorities, security

Error getting repository data for development, repository not found
```

Comment: That helps loads.  See my revised answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official Amazon Linux AMI doesn't contain the repositories that are used for phpmyadmin at all, so you'll need to install it manually.  Check out this [post by Caleb Ogden](http://www.calebogden.com/wordpress-on-linux-in-the-amazon-cloud-with-mac/) about doing just that.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, it would be preferable to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

First add the repository, then:

- install [wget](http://packages.sw.be/rpmforge-release/rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm)
- `sudo rpm -Uvh rpmforge-release-0.3.6-1.el5.rf.i386.rpm`
- `sudo yum install phpmyadmin` 

  Working fine on a standard 32 bit Amazon instance.